# pyspark cannot save data to ignite database: Py4JJavaError java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, ignite, apple-m1

I am not so familiar with spark. I tried to solve it out but could not after a few days.

My system info is as follows:

versions:

```
python version: 3.9.13 
pyspark version: 3.2.1 
py4j version: 0.10.9.3 
java version:  OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.56+19-CA (build 11.0.15+10-LTS) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.56+19-CA (build 11.0.15+10-LTS, mixed mode) 
OS version: macOS Big Sur 11.5.1 Mac M1 mini 
Chip: Apple M1
```

environment variables:

```
SPARK_HOME: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.0/libexec 
CLASSPATH: /Library/Java/Extensions/ignite-core-2.12.0.jar 
JAVA_HOME: /Applications/zulu11.56.19-ca-jdk11.0.15-macosx_aarch64/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home
```

When I used a spark read data frame, where the spark is defined as

```
        spark = SparkSession.builder.config(
            "spark.jars", "/Library/Java/Extensions/ignite-core-2.12.0.jar"
        ).getOrCreate()
```

and then want to write the read data frame to ignite database

```
spark_data_frame.write.format("jdbc").option(
            "driver", "org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver"
        ).option(
            "url", f"jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1:10800/"
        ).option(
            "dbtable", "user"
        ).mode(
            "append"
        ).save()
```

then it raises the following error:

```
virtual_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py, line326, in get_return_value
 raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o797.save.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverRegistry$.register(DriverRegistry.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.$anonfun$driverClass$1(JDBCOptions.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.$anonfun$driverClass$1$adapted(JDBCOptions.scala:101)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcOptionsInWrite.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcOptionsInWrite.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:481)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:481)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:457)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:848)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:382)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:247)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

When the call the last `save()` to save data to ignite database, it raises the problem. I am wondering that the spark already defined the spark.jars, which has the ignite jar file that includes the `org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver`. Note that ignite needs the Java 8 or Java 11 and the pyspark can support Java 11. Therefore, the java is 11 and it is the ARM version. Not sure whether it is java problem or **arm/intel** problem or spark setting problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the solution, but I'm going to say Spark settings problem because Ignite works both with Java 11 and on ARM architectures.

Comment: @StephenDarlington Thanks. You are right. This is the Spark settings problem. This problem happens when I write the unit tests for an application. It is solved by explicitly specifying the driver in the spark.jars when writing original parquets. It is wired that I need to additionally specify the driver instead of using the global environment variable $CLASSPATH or the PyCharm environment variable $CLASSPATH. This only happens in the unit tests (more accurately, the integration test). I doubt it is because in the method to be tested, there is a spark session. Maybe two sparks have conflicts.